# Innovastudio Content Builder alternatives?

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, inplace-editing

Are there any alternatives to Innovastudio Content Builder?
http://www.innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx

Features:

- In-place editing contents
- Creating custom templates
- Save output server-side

I've found Spark theme for Drupal (https://www.drupal.org/project/spark) but it's not maintained anymore and I don't want to use Drupal CMS.

Thanks for your replies!